# How to phar with encoding

Tags: php

I have no permission to copy a specified folder, so I zip this folder to another 
copyable place.

This folder contains a Chinese jpg file. 水都曲餚-主圖.jpg. How can I encode it?

pack.php

```
try {
    $phar = new PharData('project2.tar');
    $phar->buildFromDirectory(dirname(__FILE__) . '/_upload/htmlEdit/');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

> exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Entry
>   �������a-�D��.jpg cannot be created: phar error: invalid path
>   "�������a-�D��.jpg" contains illegal character' in
>   C:\Servers\www\projects\public\m000257\tk\pack.php:8 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Servers\www\projects\public\m000257\tk\pack.php(8):
>   PharData->buildFromDirectory('C:\Servers\www\...') #1 {main}

Comment: upgrade php verson solved this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `urlencode($filename)`.
All characters returned from urlencode are valid in filenames.
After that you can `urldecode()`the filenames back to UTF-8.